# Test if email delivered using Java selenium test

Tags: java, selenium

I have an automated test where we test features including sending an email to the users, i wounder if there is a way to check if the email been delivered.

the user is a test user, so i can access the mail box and check if the email is there or not, but i want to automate this process.

is there a way to do this with selenium web driver?

Comment: afaik this is way beyond the scope of selenium. Selenium is an aide to help you test your front-end, without having to manually click all the buttons, ... 
Selenium is not going to check an email account to verify whether or not a mail was received

Answer (score 0):

This is beyond the scope of selenium. What you can do is to use Mail APIs to check the mail.

For example, if you are using outlook then you use outlook rest api to check whether there is new mail or not.

Outlook API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations

If you are working on some commercial test scripting, i would ask you to out of scope this kind of tests.